# Cocoa: namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination returns only one file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I am trying to DnD a promised file. In the method:

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info item:(id)item childIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

When I see my pboard is of type `NSFilesPromisePboardType`, I do:

```
NSArray *filenames = [info namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]
```

(`info` is `NSDraggingInfo` of course).

When I drag from multiple files from applications such as Outlook for Mac, etc, `namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination` behaves as expected and "filenames" array holds as many items as it should.

However, when I drag items from Chrome (such as Gmail attachments, yes, it's possible) - I see that `pboard.pasteboardItems` does hold all the attachments, however `namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination` returns only one item!

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks a million,

Nili

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the implementation of that method depends on the 'source' and it seems that it doesn't allow to write multiple attachments to disk -- even though you can drag them. this is independent

Comment: So there's nothing I can do?

Comment: since you can't modify the source, no :(

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using promises instead of just normal files? I would recommend dumping the types that your sources are providing, there might be one much more appropriate.